# Parse, copy, and inject HTML content between files

Tags: powershell, regex, html

I'm trying to to parse HTML content from multiple text files and select specific portions of each file and copy this content to use later to paste into the content of another file.

The selected value will be injected into a specific portion of another file's content that has a matching file name, is in a different directory, and contains different content.

The file getting updated with the selected portion of the content from the other file will have some content that needs to be preserved within it and stay the same.

---

### More Detail

Suppose I have this html code from **FILE-1.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ro">
<title>YES, I love her</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
...
<div id="coloana_centru">
  <div class="container mM" id="incadrare_text_mijloc_2" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div align="justify">

        <!-- * * * * * START HERE * * * * * -->

        <p class="TATA"><em>At the mobile site I put as the header location in case the device isn't mobile? And then it executes the php code you gave stack..</em></p>
        <p class="MAMA">Simply check if the referrer is coming from within your site. If they are, they have already seen a page and have chosen where they want to go next</p>

        <!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to copy the entire text content from **FILE-1.html** starting at...

1. `<!-- * * * * * START HERE * * * * * -->`

   all the way to
2. `<!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->`

and inject this into **File-2.html** that is in a different folder in a specific region of it's file content.

For each involved file I suspect as shown in the two above strings, these values can be used as delimiters of some sort to control where to copy from and where to copy to.

This is both **FILE-1.html** and **File-2.html** side by side with annotation:

[image]

**File-2.html** that needs to be updated might look like this:

```
<section class="page_header pb-0 w-100">
    <div class="bg-overlay bg-black opacity-7"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 page-content position-relative text-white text-center">
                <h2 class="mb-3">Blog Content</h2>
                <h6 class="mb-2 text-white text-capitalize">Creativity leads to new inventions </h6>
                <a href="../index-creative-studio.html" class="d-inline-block text-white">Home</a> <span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right font-13"></i> Blog</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div id="bingo">
  <div class="container good-job" id="love" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <div class="blog-listing-inner news_item">

        <!-- * * * * * START HERE * * * * * -->

        <p class="TATA"><em> Other text 1 </em></p>
        <p class="MAMA"> Other text 2</p>

        <!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->

<div class="profile-authors heading-space-half">
    <h4 class="text-capitalize color-black mb-35px">Comments</h4>
        <div class="any-profile mb-30px">
            <div class="profile-photo"><img src="img/post6.jpg" alt="Comments"> </div>
```

Basically, I'm copying only the text article from one file to put into another file. That text, which is also with the class, are put between comments.

The problem is that I have change 3,000 files and I've only been doing this manually for much smaller sets of files, so trying to figure out a more efficient method.

**File Directories Example**
[image]

You can Replace that long comments as `<!-- * * * * * START HERE * * * * * -->` and `<!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->` with something short such as `<!--START1-->` and `<!--FINNISH1-->`

**THE BEST SOLUTION** IS THIS ONE, using **POWERSHELL**

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem 'c:\Folder1'  
$destinationFolder = 'c:\Folder2'

foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {

$sourceContent = Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw
$contentToInsert = [regex]::match($sourceContent,"(?ms)<!--START1-->(.+)<!--FINNISH1-->").value
$destinationContent = Get-Content $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Raw
$destinationContent = $destinationContent -replace '(?ms)<!--START1-->(.+)<!--FINNISH1-->',$contentToInsert

Set-Content -Path $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Value $destinationContent -Encoding UTF8

} #end foreach file
```

Comment: Perhaps [get div from HTML with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975400/get-div-from-html-with-python) will give you inspiration.

Comment: check this https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001721.htm  or check this  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this with the Windows PowerShell but since you are open to using PowerShell here's a variation to get you going that should do the trick from what I tested.

## PowerShell

```
$src = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Folder-1" -Filter "*.html";
$destFld = "c:\Folder-2";

$src | % { Process {
 
    If ( Test-Path "$destFld\$($_.Name)" ) { 

        Clear-Variable -Name ("a","b","c","x","y","z");
        $z = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw;
        $y = "`t`t<!-- $((($z -split "<!--")[1]).Trim())`r`n";
        $x = "`t`t<!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->";
        $a = Get-Content "$destFld\$($_.Name)" -Raw;
        $b = "$(($a -split "<!--")[0].Trim())`r`n";
        $c = (($a -split "<!--")[2] -Split "-->")[1].Trim();
        $b | Out-File "$destFld\$($_.Name)"; 
        $y | Out-File "$destFld\$($_.Name)" -Append; 
        $x | Out-File "$destFld\$($_.Name)" -Append; 
        $c | Out-File "$destFld\$($_.Name)" -Append; 
        
        }
}};
```

---

#### Before and After Result Examples

**File-1.html (used for update content)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ro">
<title>YES, I love her</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
...
<div id="coloana_centru">
  <div class="container mM" id="incadrare_text_mijloc_2" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div align="justify">

        <!-- * * * * * START HERE * * * * * -->

        <p class="TATA"><em>At the mobile site I put as the header location in case the device isn't mobile? And then it executes the php code you gave stack..</em></p>
        <p class="MAMA">Simply check if the referrer is coming from within your site. If they are, they have already seen a page and have chosen where they want to go next</p>

        <!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**File-2.html (before update)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ro">
<title>No, I do NOT love her because she too ugly</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
...
<div id="SheTooUgly">
  <div class="container mM" id="incadrare_doc_mijloc_33" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div align="justify">

        <!-- * * * * * START HERE * * * * * -->

        <p class="TATA"><em>Girl too ugly to love</em></p>
        <p class="MAMA">She way too ugly, yuk</p>

        <!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**File-2.html (after update)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ro">
<title>No, I do NOT love her because she too ugly</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
...
<div id="SheTooUgly">
  <div class="container mM" id="incadrare_doc_mijloc_33" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div align="justify">

        <!-- * * * * * START HERE * * * * * -->

        <p class="TATA"><em>At the mobile site I put as the header location in case the device isn't mobile? And then it executes the php code you gave stack..</em></p>
        <p class="MAMA">Simply check if the referrer is coming from within your site. If they are, they have already seen a page and have chosen where they want to go next</p>

        <!-- * * * * * END HERE * * * * * -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)
- [Clear-Variable](https://ss64.com/ps/clear-variable.html)
- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [Out-File](https://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html)
- [About Special Characters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.1)

  > a. **`t** :   *Horizontal tab*
  >
  > b. **`n** :   New line
  >
  > c. **`r** :   Carriage return
  >
  > Where c. and b. : `CRLF` EOL
- [How-to: Change the line endings of a text file](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-set-eol.html)